# Node Sending CSV File and Getting Back New File + Status Message

Tags: node.js, csv

I am building an app that reads a single (in the future can be multiple) CSV file. Once I send it off, I have a service that will modify the CSV file(s) and send back a new copy of the file that will be automatically downloaded by the browser. With that copy, I want to send some status message (IE: 100 of 101 contacts synced. One error found). What is the best way to do this?

Base 64 encoding the file has been ruled out (would allow for JSON of the status message but we don't want to do this). Adding custom headers with the status message is the leading contender (IE: res.setHeader('X-Process-Status': status)).

Is there a better way to do this? We are using Node.

Comment: why dont you just prefer default methods what the rest of the world use for data exchange such as xml or json ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. I'm trying to get back both the new file and a status message (which I'm totally ok with being JSON) back in one response

Comment: Have you considered having the browser make a second request to get the status message?

Comment: Yeah but I'm trying to do it in one

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correct you have a csv you want to post it to server update ad send back alongside with the status.
In this case you can simply write a rest api as your back end and use json to communicate your backend could simply return a json data similar to

```
{
"data":"<your csv>",
"code":<your status code>
}
```

and since there is a json parser built inside javascript you could parse it using

```
data=JSON.parse(response)
```

then you could use data however you wish

```
//the csv data
data.data
//the status code
data.code
```